# Disable offline data transfer in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Currently i am facing an issue, sometimes i need an user be able to send message only when others can receive it in firebase. By default, i see that firebase only queues the data that is to be transferred. For instance i have a code which goes like this :

```
 Map<Object, Object> map = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
 map.put("message", messageText);
 databaseReference.push().setValue(map);
```

Even when user is offline, a listner is always listening to anything that is being pushed and original user sees that the message have been sent. But, its actually creating a problem. Even if message will be sent on later time, user already sees the message and becomes assured that messag have been sent.

So, i want something like

```
 if(connection.ActuallySent())
{
     Map<Object, Object> map = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
     map.put("message", messageText);
     databaseReference.push().setValue(map); 
}else
{
toast("Please try again..");
}
```

Is this possible ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to deal with this is to show an indication to the user that the message hasn't been delivered to the Firebase server yet. To know when this happened, you attach a completion listener to the `setValue` call.

```
databaseReference.push().setValue(map, new Firebase.CompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(FirebaseError firebaseError, Firebase firebase) {
        if (firebaseError != null) {
            System.out.println("Data could not be saved. " + firebaseError.getMessage());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Data saved successfully.");
        }
    }
});
```

If instead you want to only write when the user is connected to Firebase, you can [attach a listener to `.info/connected`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state) and only call `setValue` when this is `true`.

```
bool connected = false;

DatabaseReference connectedRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(".info/connected");
connectedRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    connected = snapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
    System.err.println("Listener was cancelled");
  }
});
```

And then:

```
if (connected) {
     Map<Object, Object> map = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
     map.put("message", messageText);
     databaseReference.push().setValue(map); 
}
```

Comment: .info/connected how to use this

Comment: I always need to check if its connected when sending every message. But in this .info/connected code, it always becomes true when its once connected.

Comment: The listener on `.info/connected` stays active, so if you make `connected` a member field it will always have the correct value. If that doesn't work for you, it's likely caused by how you wired things up. It's best if you update your question to show what you've tried in an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).